# How to fetch query string from the url in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got a route which may have different syntax according to the tokenid

```
<Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <HomePageComponent />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/verify/:tokenId" component={EmailTarget}>
</Switch>
```

What i am trying to do is i am trying to grab what is in the place of `:tokenId`.

Here what code look like inside the Email Target Component.

```
const EmailTarget: React.FC = ( props ) => {
    const [ loginState, setLoginState ] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
              console.log(props.match.params.tokenId)
    }, [])
```

What I am doing now is simply console logging the tokenId.
But the typescript is giving me error.

Here is the error log

```
C:/Users/kerry/Desktop/works/rslabs/src/components/EmailTarget.tsx
TypeScript error in C:/Users/kerry/Desktop/works/rslabs/src/components/EmailTarget.tsx(14,27):
Property 'match' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

The strange thing about this situation is that I can console.log the tokenId and actually giving me the result but the program is giving me an error.

Please don't give minus to this question. If you give a minus please mention the area I need to improve in the question first.

Comment: What is the output for console.log(props)?
Also, did you check https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params ?

I know their example doesn't use typescript, but it uses a useParams() hook instead.

Comment: Are you using the withRouter HoC on your component? That is withRouter(EmailTarget) ? If not Typescript won't recognize you are trying to use React Router props.

Comment: this props actually return the same props as in react

Comment: @DiegoPedro actually i am using it

I am exporting withRouter(App) like this

Comment: @Kerry Then take a look at @merko answer as it is the correct one. Typescript cannot infer you are in a Route and therefore able to access `RouteComponentProps`

Comment: @DiegoPedro Thanks for your hint. Now I see the cause. IDK why my question got minus. do you have any idea why i got a minus? Now i am obsessed over it. Since I am asking the same question 2 times because i got a minus

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend component props with `RouteComponentProps` type, it includes everything you need.

Example:

```
const Component = ({
  history,
  match: {
    params: { id },
  },
}: YourProps & RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }>)
```